# I have a component that I am trying to test, which utilises a hook that exports a function. How to mock the exported function before the test?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, react-native-testing-library

I have a hook called `useStartGame` which exports just 1 function like this:

```
const useStartGame = () => {
    const startGame = (game) => { //Do something }

    return { startGame };
}
```

Now I have a component which uses this hook, however, I want to overwrite what the function does in my test. I tried adding the following code in my test:

```
jest.mock('@src/hooks/useStartGame', () => ({
    useStartGame: () => {
        return { startGame: jest.fn() };
    },
}));
```

However, in my test I get this error:

```
TypeError: (0 , _useStartGame2.default) is not a function
```

Comment: That's the _default_ export (although you don't show that), but you're mocking it like a _named_ export.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Would it be possible to show me an example of how it should be done?

Comment: There are examples in the docs: https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#mock-modules